# How to Mock a readonly property whose value depends on another property of the Mock

Tags: c#, .net, moq

(As indicated by the tags, I am using moq).

I have an interface like this:

```
interface ISource
{
  string Name { get; set; }
  int Id { get; set; }
}

interface IExample
{
  string Name { get; }
  ISource Source { get; set; }
}
```

In my application, concrete instances of IExample accept a DTO (IDataTransferObject) as the Source.  Some properties on the concrete implementation of IExample are simply delegated to the Source.  Like this...

```
class Example : IExample
{
  IDataTransferObject Source { get; set; }

  string Name { get { return _data.Name; } }
}
```

I would like to create a standalone mock of IExample (standalone meaning that I cannot use a captured variable because several instances of the IExample mock will be created in the course of a test) and setup the Mock such that IExample.Name returns the value of IExample.Source.Name.  So, I would like to create a mock something like this:

```
var example = new Mock<IExample>();
example.SetupProperty(ex => ex.Source);
example.SetupGet(ex => ex.Name).Returns(what can I put here to return ex.Source.Name);
```

Essentially, I want to configure the mock to return, as the value of one property, the value of a property of a subobject of the mock.

Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could probably use:

```
example.SetupGet(ex => ex.Name).Returns(() => example.Object.Source.Name);
```

The value to be returned will then be determined when the property is accessed, and will be taken from `Name` property of the mock's `Source` property.

Comment: That does exactly what I want.  It never occurred to me to capture the local variable that is the Mock that I want to reference to get the underlying value of.  It makes my brain hurt.

Comment: note that you don't need a lambda in this case. Simply use `.Returns(example.Object.Source.Name)`, at least for recent versions of Moq.

Comment: @Pac0 - the lambda approach should work in all cases, whilst passing the value of the property will only give the correct results when the value is unchanging and available at the point the mock is set up. If the property could return different values at different points in time then the lambda is the only option.

Comment: that's definitely a good argument in favor of using lambda, you are right. And in any case it's good to understand that the two versions are not behaving the same way,